# HTML Google map not shown in right-to-left languages and narrow screen

Tags: html, google-maps, forms

I have a problem in my site with Google maps working with right-to-left languages. When the screen width is small - i.e. mobile device or tab -, the map is not shown at all.

Here is how its style is defined:

```
<style>
#form-map{
    background-color: #e5e3df;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
#form-map img { max-width: none; }
</style>
```

and it is shown in English correctly:

[image]

But in Arabic, it is not shown at all:

[image]

Comment: Is there an error message in the browser console?

Comment: @ceejayoz no at all, it works fine in English version, but when convert to Arabic map is not shown although the screen width is the same in both cases !!

Comment: Providing more code should help

Comment: I can suggest writing a small example that demonstrates this issue on https://jsfiddle.net/ and report the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/